# Check date range from From and To Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table

```
ProductId   Name    FromDate    To Date
1           A       1-Jan 2017       10-Jan 2017
2           B       5-Feb 2017       5-Feb 2017
```

Whenver I am inserting a new record in grid I have to check whether record for selected range date exist or not  for that particular name

For example for Name B if new record comes daterange(5 Jan 2017 to 15 Jan 2017)
as  5th jan -10th jan  already exist , it should return false or product id.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You probably need a trigger for this.

Comment: "Whenver I am inserting"... are you using a script, a stores procedure, a SSIS package?

Comment: i am using stored procedure

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the procedure? It shouldn't be a problem to check for the ID before you insert the record...

Comment: Currently in procedure i have the simple insert query,validation is yet to achieve to avoid insertion of duplicate data

Comment: add `where not exists (appropriate subquery)` to your simple insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script, this will return the `ProductId` if there is any conflict / overlap with the existing date range

```
DECLARE @Input_From DATE --your from date here
        ,@Input_To  DATE --your to date here

SELECT  ProductId
FROM    Product_Table
WHERE   Name = 'B'
    AND (   @Input_From BETWEEN FromDate    AND ToDate
        OR  @Input_To   BETWEEN FromDate    AND ToDate
        OR  FromDate    BETWEEN @Input_From AND @Input_To
    )
```

Comment: you don't need the last or condition, both above imply it

Comment: @RaulSebastian, its required, we have to address following scenarios. 1. Todate within an  existing period( ^__[__^_]). 2. From within an existing period([__ ^__]__^). 3. Fromdate is before existing period and Todate also after the existing slot( ^__[__]_^), that is the existing period is completely within the entered date rage. Then only the overlap checking work properly.

Comment: Can be simplified to `@input_from <= ToDate AND @input_to >= FromDate`

Comment: @MatBailie, have you checked all the above possibilities?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed yes, I've used it in production environments for about 10 years.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed you are absolutely right, I didn't think of the last scenario.

Comment: @MatBailie you are right, it is absolutely working fine there is no need to add any other condition

Answer (score 1):

'inputDate' can be applied to both from and to date. In this way, range can be verified:

```
select t.productId from table t
where inputDate between t.FromDate and t.toDate
and t.Name = 'B'
```

In your sproc add a check like this:

```
declare @pid int = (
    select t.productId from table t
    where inputDate between t.FromDate and t.toDate
    and t.Name = @name)
if @pid is null
    return cast(0 as bool)
else
    return @pid
```

Comment: Thanx for the response. But I have two input dates(From and To) so this would not work

Comment: do you need to check both date in range ? if yes then try this 
select t.productId from table t
where (inputFromDate between t.FromDate and t.toDate 
      or inputToDate between t.FromDate and t.toDate )
and t.Name = 'B'

Comment: It's to check if two Periods Of Time overlap.  Such as "Was Einstein alive while Elvis was alive?".  Checking a Birthday alone doesn't help.